# how to solve the following error ""Syntax Error: Expected Name, found <EOF>"

Tags: javascript, graphql

Trying to make the following request:

```
axios({
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
        },
        method: 'post',
        url: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql',
        data: {
          query: `mutation {login(email: "myEmail", password: "MyCoolPasswordHello") {token refreshToken}`,
        },
      }).then(function(response) {
        console.log('done');
      });
```

Should resmble playground:

```
mutation
{
    login(email:"myEmail", password:"MyCoolPasswordHello")
  {token
  refreshToken}
}
```

But I keep getting

```
Syntax Error: Expected Name, found <EOF>
```

Comment: error is in http://localhost:4000/graphql , not in js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a '}' in your query:

```
mutation {login(email: "myEmail", password: "MyCoolPasswordHello") {token refreshToken}} <- HERE
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw this error despite me having the correct number of closing braces.  However, it turned out that comments in the JSON meant that while they query worked in Postman, it failed in curl.

Removing the comments solved the problem.